# How is it possible to answer a closed question without asking for it to be reopened?

Tags: discussion, privileges

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475056/138900) was closed by a prominent contributor with 87 gold badges including the `boxes` badge (which tags this question) at 4:48 pm.

Another prominent contributor with 9 gold badges himself, but not the `boxes` badge, responded at 5:44 p. m., almost an hour later.

I thought that no one could answer a closed question and I realize that no: some contributors have unsuspected privileges.

- How is that possible?
- What is the privilege of responding to a closed question without having to reopen it?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: Hmm, this looks like one for the staff: that shouldn't happen!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed

Comment: Seems this is a 'feature'

Comment: The explanations given in these links are worth testing. We should write a stupid question and close it. And we should try to answer them to see if what is said in these links is true or false.

Comment: I just tested this with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474183/35864 and it worked (post now deleted to avoid confusion, a screenshot can be found at https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S2wu.png). I could add an answer roughly two hours after the question was closed.

Comment: @moewe I take your word for it because your screenshots do not show the closing date or the answer date. Can you give us an answer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922) (found by [Joseph Wright](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) in the [comments](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8104/how-is-it-possible-to-answer-a-closed-question-without-asking-for-it-to-be-reope#comment25587_8104)) the server accepts answers to closed questions for a grace period of up to four hours after they were closed.

If one starts writing an answer before the question is closed or just has the question opened in a tab in un-closed state one can just still submit an answer.

It is even possible to submit an answer to a now closed question if one does not have access to an un-closed version of the question. The method is described in [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922) and works by manipulating the HTML code of an open question to submit to the now closed one. I verified that that indeed works with [BibLaTeX Title goes into the margin in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474183/35864). I managed to submit another answer (which I immediately deleted) some two hours after it was closed.

[image: Screenshot of the now deleted test answer: The question was closed '6 hours ago', the answer posted and deleted '4 hours' ago]

Now you might ask whether I might have a secret privilege that allowed me to do that. If you want to absolutely make sure that that is not the case you (or you as unregistered user) can try and submit an answer to  [(solved) mdframed - different skip heights after page break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474682) in the next 45 minutes or so. I didn't bother to do that because I have already posted enough (fake) answers today to annoy the community.

Comment: Thank you very much for your essays and your answer. I find this surreal.